# Flask and AngularJs

Tags: python, html, angularjs, flask

I am trying to implement AngularJs to my flask project. In my app.py I have this code to render a test site:

```
@app.route('/test/')
def test():
    return render_template('test.html')
```

And in the test.html I have this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <title>Flask-Triangle - Tutorial</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
    <hr>
    <h1>Hello {{ yourName }}!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I type in the input field nothing is happen..
I have checked that the angular.min.js is correctly loaded.
Is there something I have to do in app.py to get this work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Flask uses jinja as its templating language which also uses `{{ variable }}`

so when flask renders the templates `{{ yourname }}` just becomes an empty string since yourname is not a context variable in the current render

to fix this you can use `flask-triangle`
http://flask-triangle.readthedocs.org/en/develop/tutorial/part1.html

which provides a template filter

`{{ yourname | angular }}` that will ensure the template is rendered correct for angular

you could also use escaped brackets inside the brackets (but this is much uglier I think)

`{{ '{{ yourname }}' }}`

Comment: It worked! Thank you

Answer (score 9):

Another way to fix this is that you can wrap the entire test.html contents with `{% raw %}` at the top, and `{% endraw %}` at the bottom.  This will tell jinja not to do anything special in this.  This way would ***only*** be good if you are not planning on using jinja at all.  Using this would also make it a bit nicer to write with, as you no longer have to add in the fixes that [Joran Beasley suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32147748/flask-and-angularjs/32147806#32147806).

Example:

```html
{% raw %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- HEADER STUFF -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Normal AngularJS code and syntax -->
  </body>
</html>
{% endraw %}
```